# Extract Name and Email on each new line of a textfile into a database for newsletter

Tags: php, text-files

I'm working on a newsletter app where we would upload the names and emails of each member into a database. The notepad file looks like this:

```
Jimmy Alewa
jimmyalewa@yahoo.com

Sam
sam@oeins.com

Dr. Peter Mark
drmark98@yaoo.bh
```

I have been getting conflicting results trying different methods. 
My aim is to get 2 lines each and then to further explode in one line each and save the email against the name of a member in a MySql database.

I tried this, no luck

```
  $text_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

   $fh = fopen($text_file, 'r');

  while(!feof($fh))
{
    echo $data[] = fgets($fh); 
    echo "<br>";
    //Do whatever you want with the data in here
    //This feeds the file into an array line by line
}
fclose($fh);
```

I couldn't get 2 lines each first. If i get 2 lines each, I will further break into 1 line each and save as array[0] for name and array[1] for email in each loop.

Please assist me if you could. Regards

*UPDATE:
With the help of Abra..I got the answer, see my codes below and check out Abra's code for more clarifications:

```
$textfile = file_get_contents($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]);
$lines  = file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | 
FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$result = array_chunk($lines, 2); 
print("<pre>".print_r($result,true)."</pre>");

foreach($result as $list){

    echo $list[0]."&nbsp;";
    echo $list[1];
    echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second approach of getting 2 lines each?

Comment: Use `file` to read the lines into an array, then loop over the resulting array using `for`. Then you can access `$foo[$i]` and `$foo[$i+1]` inside the loop, and you simply increase the loop counter by 3 instead of the usual 1, to move on to the next “set” of lines after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is consistent, just read in the non-empty lines and chunk it into 2 lines:

```
$lines  = file($text_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$result = array_chunk($lines, 2);
```

Should result in something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jimmy Alewa
            [1] => jimmyalewa@yahoo.com
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sam
            [1] => sam@oeins.com
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dr. Peter Mark
            [1] => drmark98@yaoo.bh
        )
)
```